# spawning objects not removing after leaving scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

Hi my objects are not removing after leaving the scene, i have tried to purging and removing the scene, but the objects will just keep on spawning in a other scene?

```
local badclout1 = {} 
local bad1Group = display.newGroup()
local function spawnBC1()
   local badclouts1 = display.newImage("BCloud1.png")
   badclouts1.x = math.random(0, _W)
   physics.addBody( badclouts1, "dynamic", { density=.1, bounce=.1, friction=.2, radius=45 } )       
   badclouts1.name = "BCloud1" 
   badclouts1.bodyType = "kinematic"
   badclouts1.isSensor = true
   badclouts1.y = math.random(-100, -50)
   badclouts1.index = #badclout1 + 1
   bad1Group:insert(badclouts1)
   badclouts1.rotation = math.random(-10,10) -- Rotate the object
   badclouts1:setLinearVelocity(0, math.random(speeda1, speedb1)) -- Drop down
   badclout1[badclouts1.index] = badclouts1
   tmrSpawn1 = timer.performWithDelay(math.random(spawna, spawnb), spawnBC1)
return badclouts1 
end
tmrSpawn1 = timer.performWithDelay(math.random(1000, 10000), spawnBC1)
 local function removeBomb()
  for i, v in pairs(badclout1) do
    if badclout1[i].y >1000 then
        badclout1[i]:removeSelf()
        badclout1[i] = nil
     end
  end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", removeBomb)
```

is there something in my code that keeps it on the screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cancel your `performWithDelay` function using `timer.cancel(tmrSpawn1)`. Because you're calling it recursively, it will just keep going until you cancel it.

Comment: the dit not start again because i didn't use storyboar correctly